# See only relevant questions?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, filtering

I want to have a way to see unanswered questions that are related to my tags and topics.

Is this implemented? How can I do that?

I would love to contribute more with the little knowledge I have accumulated in 20 years of internet coding. But the "questions" list on stackoverflow looks so irrelevant to me. It seems very odd that when I have never asked or answered a c# question, I have to wade through c# questions, for instance. I can't believe stackoverflow doesn't use the data it has from my account to prioritize or filter questions.

---

UPDATE:

Thanks to @Pekka, I discovered the "Favorite Tags" section which in turn (when used) gets me an "interesting" filter for the questions.

So I am now just left with the question why stackoverflow wouldn't let me infer my "interests" from the questions and answers and comments I contribute.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: You are on the"interesting" tab and it's showing you only irrelevant questions? That shouldn't be. Have you defined your "interesting" tags?

Comment: I don't see an "interesting" tab in stackoverflow. Do you mean "hot"?

Comment: [Interesting](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting)

Comment: Thanks Pekka - I guess it is correlated with the "favorite tags". Now that I set one, the "interesting" tab was added.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There might not be enough data yet in your profile to have the [algorithms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152527/stack-overflow-interesting-questions-implementation) work for you.

If you visit your [preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/1598477) you can add tags you consider to be your [favorite or add tags you like to ignore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do).

This is how my ignore list looks (I don't have any favorites):

[image: ignored tags]

The link to your [prediction data](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data) is at the bottom of that same page.

Beyond that you can use the [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bjavascript%5d%20or%20%20%5bjquery%5d%20answers%3a0%20closed%3ano) capabilities to find questions in specific tags. The advanced help search is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) and the search result page it self has the most common commands in the side-bar

[image: search with search commands]

If you are looking for even more control over search results you can use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to query directly on the weekly data-dump from production.

Comment: Wow, with an ignore list that long, how many questions do you actually see?

Comment: Just enough to keep me occupied... @matsjoyce

Comment: The link to [preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) in this answer should include ".../current" rather than an actual ".../1598477" userid.

Answer (score 2):

why bother about filtering tags. the site's search function also provides wild card entries so, add your favourite tags/topics within square brackets and separate them using `or` keyword.
for example, if you want to have all unanswered questions of `c`,`c++` or `java` then search with this `[c++] or [c] or [java]` in search bar.
after getting the page, click on `newest` and bookmark it so that you don't have to enter the search terms again and again.