# How to ignore/dismiss a question

Tags: discussion

This seems like a straightforward question, but I can't find the answer sorry.

I'm trying to do something useful by answering questions I know how to answer. I can search for a set of questions, go through it, and answer the ones I know. Now, in the list, there are many questions I know I can't answer, and these questions keep popping up when I do the same search periodically to answer new questions. There are also many questions which already have an answer that I find satisfactory, and for which I cannot contribute anymore.

Is there a way to mark these questions as "ignored", "dismissed", "not interesting for me" or so, so that the do not show up next time I do a search?

I know I can search by tags to find questions I *might* be interested in (as advised in the answers of [See only relevant questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289413/see-only-relevant-questions)), but no search can know in advance whether I know how to answer or whether I find the current answer satisfactory. So, what I'm looking for is a way to mark questions as ignored manually and individually.

I did find a similar feature when I answer a question, I get a button "answer similar questions" and then get a list of questions, each of which have a button "Answer this question", and a link "dismiss" next to it. But this "dismiss" link does not appear when I do a normal search, and questions marked as "dismiss" there still pop up in the next searches.

Comment: How about filtering tags? Questions with a tag you marked as favorite will be yellow, while a question with a tag you marked as ignored will be grey

Comment: I do filter with tags. But once I get the list many of the questions are still not interesting to me. What I'm looking for is a way to manually filter the list obtained by an automatic search.

Comment: I fundamentally disagree that this question is "identical" to the indicated one "See only relevant questions?" I **LOVE** Matthieu's approach, exactly as he phrased it, and the other question merely talks about tags. Matthieu (and I!) want a way to effectively read a question once, dismiss it, and never see it again. **NEVER**. We've looked at it, and decided that we can't help, or that it has been sufficiently answered. The act of dismissing any question (as far as I'm concerned) could be irrevocable.