# Need dashboard for people who primarily answer questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions

I think there needs to be a clearly marked *answerer's dashboard*.  Something that's clearly labelled with text that is direct and obvious like: *Answer Questions*.

My motivation question was: *How do I discover the way to see the list of questions that I am most likely to be able to answer?* and I think the current correct approach is to use the [interesting](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) tab.  [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289414/1563833) explains why it's probably the right place to go if you want to answer questions and find questions that are relevant to your expertise. That post seems to answer my questions of **What's the best way to put relevant questions in front of me?** and **How do I describe my area of expertise to Stack Overflow?**  But it has taken me years to find that post - so I would argue that it's not easily discoverable.

So, if the way to find questions that you can answer is to hit the *interesting* button.  I think that it's currently too hard to figure that out.  And I'm still not convinced that *interesting* is actually is the best way to get connected with questions that you can answer - that further work could be done - and if there were an answerer's dashboard, that said work might actually get done.

My feature request is to make it more obvious how to find relevant questions to answer and make a clearly discoverable dashboard with efficient workflow for answerers - to make it a more answerer-friendly site.

Comment: There is an ongoing new navigation development. I don't see the need for any new navigation effort until we get the new nav officially released.

Comment: You think that things will be better with this "new navigation effort".  What is that?  Respectfully, can you link that information to me please?

Comment: You don't think *the homepage* is easily discoverable?  It's...the homepage...

Comment: It does not put the most relevant questions in front of me.  The homepage is a long list questions tagged with things that I care about, but that I'm not the right one to answer.  I have to go digging for questions.  It is *never* the case for me that there's anything answerable even in the top 10 of the homepage.  So no.

Comment: @Wyck can't really find the link, it was phased out a few months ago, but you should have seen it. They were tabs with preferences, save-able, with a few interesting features. Not sure what's on the menu for those. It's pretty much what you ask for.

Comment: you may find this useful: [stack-overflow-stack-exchange-advanced-search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270548/stack-overflow-stack-exchange-advanced-search)

Comment: To all those who downvoted:  My point is that it's not obvious that "interesting" questions are "questions that I'm most likely to be able to answer".

Comment: [Voting is different on Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) especially when it comes to feature requests.

Comment: Yes, I read that before I posted, @MikeMcCaughan.  But I'm astonished that people are rejecting the notion that "interesting" doesn't mean "relevant to my expertise".

Comment: It could be that they are rejecting the idea of creating a "clearly discoverable dashboard with efficient workflow for answerers"... but I have no idea. I find questions easily enough with the technique given by meagar.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I agree, and, well, that's on me then.  I can see how people have conflated conveying intent, with functionality based on the way I provided my motivating question as context.

Answer (score 10):

This already exists, its address is `https://stackoverflow.com/`. You don't have to "hit the interesting button", you're already on it when you land on Stack Overflow.

Configure your favorite tags and your ignored tags, and https://stackoverflow.com/ is *exactly* what you're describing: A list of questions that you are likely interested in answering.

Comment: See my comment on the previous.  I don't find any answerable questions on the home page.  I have to go mining for them.

Comment: Then you should configure your favorite tags.

Comment: I have fav tags.  The homepage puts answered questions in front of me - as one example of many reasons it has shortcomings to an answerer.

Comment: @Wyck you can provide an answer for an already answered question. Maybe you have a better answer than the existing ones. You may have noticed that many questions have multiple answers.

Comment: @Wyck The answered questions that are on the homepage are questions with answers *that don't have a high score*, meaning that there isn't a high confidence that they are the answer.  The higher the scores on the answers, the lower the ranking on the homepage.

Comment: Yes, I'll continue using the homepage.  I'll tweak tags.  I'll trust the AI / ranking.  Thanks.

Comment: I would undo my downvote of this answer based on @MikeMcCaughan's insight of the misinterpretation of my suggestion. - If only stack overflow would let me.  Oh well.

Comment: I've given it a couple of months since my first complaint.  In following @meagar's advice, I configured my favourite and ignored tags and things have gotten a lot better.  Now there are yellow-highlighted questions on the home page that are actually relevant.  There are still white ones that are irrelevant.  At the time of me writing my original post, there were NO yellow-marked questions for me.  This behaviour is new and seems to have to do with configuring favourites and ignored.  (is it?) If so, then again I would have reason to upvote this answer.  Things are much better.