# Can we add a soft "ignore" flag to questions to help users exclude questions from search results?

Tags: feature-request, search, bookmarks

I am trying to monitor specific tags and at least review each unanswered question with that tag. Over time I keep seeing the same questions that I do not want to answer for whatever reason, which makes it harder to find the questions that I haven't yet processed.

This is not the same as *[See only relevant questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289413/see-only-relevant-questions)* as this is on an individual posts within specified tags.

There is another scenario. As a user, I have posted a question that has not received a response, and in my time researching I have identified a search query that shows up other similar questions, but these do not have responses that assist me. Now periodically I run the same search query, but I have identified a number of results that I want to exclude. Either they are low quality or do not match my requirements, but skipping through multiple pages to check activity is annoying. I don't remember the titles of the posts, but once I read them I very quickly remember that I don't want to see this again.

So there are a few mechanisms that could help these scenarios:

1. Just as I can *bookmark* or *favourite* a post, I would like to be able to *ignore* individual posts.

   - I **do not** think it's useful to display a count of these ignores publicly. This isn't about popularity, but more about personal situational relevance.
   - search results can still show the ignored posts, but they could be styled differently, perhaps in collapsed view, or greyed out, something to show them less prominently than other results
   - we could use a search argument to exclude *ignored* posts
2. *This is more involved, but it has wider applications*. Add a feature where we can add our own private tags to posts.
3. An alternate implementation of (2) instead of private tags, is to replace/extend the *bookmark* feature so that we can create our own *book mark **names***, effectively creating multiple book mark collections.

   - this add more usable value to 'bookmarks' for users. Right now, bookmark is not hugely useful feature, unless I remember to un-mark the items over time. The list of bookmarked posts becomes just as unmanageable as the rest, allowing us to create names for our personal bookmarks, means we can add a layer of organisation to them. We can create logical groups so we remember over time why that post was marked and why it might be significant down the track.
   - Understanding the load on the system if users can create an unlimited number of bookmark types, I'm happy for a limit, or make it similar to Outlook Categories, where under the hood there is a finite list of categories, however as users we can rename them in our UI.

> If similar features exist for higher privileged users, I'm happy to work on my rep and badges, but also request that such features become available to tags that we have earned badges in because this could really assist me to help with the tags that I am proficient in, and also encourage me to gain rep and be more active in other tags.

Comment: You should be able to tell easily which questions you've visited already and not bother to return to them again. Unfortunately, with Stack Overflow's default theme, there's nothing "easy" about discerning visited links from unvisited. A bit of CSS injection will fix that right up for you. I've made my visited links on SO a nice purple (crazy, right? where'd I ever come up with that color idea?!).

Comment: Thanks @CodyGray the links thing means it only works on a single workstation, SO is the only constant that stays with me over the years, the desktop/pc/laptop device in use changes almost weekly. But its a better hack than nothing, after all I'm interested in hearing how others deal with these issues. I still think there is scope to add more functional value to bookmarks and have updated my post to reflect that

Comment: Or instead of bookmark names, ability to tag bookmarks (user-defined tags and corresponding filter capabilities).

Comment: How-to for Firefox (may or may not still work for Chrome): *[How can I change link colors in Firefox and Chrome, but leave all other colors and fonts as they are?](https://superuser.com/questions/638250/how-can-i-change-link-colors-in-firefox-and-chrome-but-leave-all-other-colors-a/638257#638257)*. (The part about `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheet` ***is*** required in later versions of Firefox.)

Comment: Though Firefox sometimes forgets it has visited pages, even on the same day/in the same session.

Comment: @PeterMortensen some of the links you've visited might even be different. For example, if you went to a question via the Linked tab, it has extra stuff added to the end. Another example is if the title of the question changes - that also changes the link itself. So, Firefox is sometimes justified.